# Evaluate the determinant with Identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Hello all I learning about determinants and this problem currently has me completely stumped.  I can not figure how the answer in the book was achieved.

Problem:

$\det(\lambda I_2 - A)$  where 
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 2 \\ -1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix} $$

The book answer is: 
 $ \lambda^2 - 5 \lambda + 6$

I could only figure out how the 6 was found.  I would like to note we haven't gone over eigenvalues either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing about eigenvalues here. It's a simple calculation: 
$$\lambda I_2 - A = \left[\array{\lambda - 4 & -2 \\ 1 & \lambda - 1}\right],$$

so its determinant is $(\lambda - 4)(\lambda - 1) + 2 = \lambda^2 - 5\lambda + 6$ by the standard determinant formula for $2\times 2$ matrices.

Comment: How did you know how use lambda on the diagnol, my book doesn't mention this notation I believe.

Comment: Matrix should be $$\begin{bmatrix}\lambda-4&-2\\1&\lambda+1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @Dave are you sure I user3482749 is correct.

Comment: @user1238097 I am sure. Indeed, $$\lambda I-A=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&0\\0&\lambda\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}4&2\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix}$$ Notice the minus sign in front of $A$.

Comment: @Dave you are definitely right.  I am at a loss on the book answer still. I realized I added a negative a22 of the matrix on accident.

Comment: @Dave Oops, failed at reading. Yours wasn't right either, though.

Comment: @user1238097 $\lambda I_2 = \left[\array{\lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda}\right]$.